# Python - switching positions: list[i], list[list.index(minimum)] = list[list.index(minimum)], list[i]

Tags: python, list, position, swap

could anyone explain me, why is it not possible to swap list positions in my function for selection sort?
This is what i wrote at first, but the function returns the same list as the input:

```
def selection_sort(list):
    for i in range(0, len(list)):
        minimum = list[i]
        for j in range(i + 1, len(list)):
            if list[j] < minimum:
                minimum = list[j]
        list[i], list[list.index(minimum)] = list[list.index(minimum)], list[i]
    return list
```

Then I tried to use a variable index = list.index(minimum) and suddenly it worked.

```
def selection_sort(list):
    for i in range(0, len(list)):
        minimum = list[i]
        for j in range(i + 1, len(list)):
            if list[j] < minimum:
                minimum = list[j]
        index = list.index(minimum)
        list[i], list[index] = list[index], list[i]
    return list
```

Could anyone explain me the difference and why is it not corect the first solution?
Thank you!

Comment: Try this: `lst = [1, 2, 3, 4] ; lst[1], lst[(idx1 := lst.index(3))] = lst[(idx2 := lst.index(3))], lst[1]` and check values of `idx1` and `idx2`. That's the answer.

Comment: @OlvinRoght That's so weird -- how does `idx1` get set to 1 *before* the swap is made?

Comment: @Samwise, that's how it works -> [tio](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P60oP1chJbNYITO3IL@oBMTk4kpJTVNIK81L1ijOLy1KTo3PySwu0VEoLkksyUyOz8xLSa3QUShLzClN1bTiUgACJGXRyKpidVClEGw9sLwGxJBYBVvi1OngtomLq6AoM69EA@h@DZDTNTX//wcA).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right hand side of the assignment (`list[list.index(minimum)], list[i]`) is computed first, then assigned to the tuple on the left `list[i], list[list.index(minimum)]`.

I'm guessing the next part, but I assume `list[i]` is assigned to, then `list[list.index(minimum)]`. However, since you've already assigned to `list[i]` you've already modified the list before finding `list.index(minimum)` a second time. Since you're not searching in identical lists, the indexes may be different.

Your second attempt calculates the index once and uses the same value in both places.

As a side note, it is good practice to not name variables the same as a python builtin name.  Your function takes a parameter called `list` so that "shadows" the builtin `list` function. You wouldn't be able to call that builtin inside your function because the name has been stolen.  Better to call it `my_list`, `array`, or `list_to_sort` etc.